# React Equivalent for JQuery form with Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I need to call the following function on a plugin integration I have:

```
 window.ExternalApi.initExternalSettingControls = (controls) => {
    controls.push({
      name: 'myControl',
      render() {
        $(this.domContainer).html(
          '<div class="form-group">\
            <div class="col-xs-12">\
              <label for="controlValue">Link ID</label>\
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="controlValue">\
            </div>\
          </div>');
        let inputField = $('#controlValue');

        inputField.val($(this.domElement).find('a[link-id]').attr('link-id'));
        inputField.keyup(function(e) {
          $(this.domElement).find('a').attr('link-id', e.target.value);
          this.applyChanges();
        }.bind(this));
      }
    });
  };
```

It works fine but my Application is not Jquery based but React based. I don't have any Jquery knowledge and I would like to convert this call into standard JS and React. How can I do that ?

Comment: Instead of using find, you need to create Refs and access them in your methods. More info available at https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 0):

```
  window.StripoApi.initExternalSettingControls = (controls) => {
    controls.push({
      name: 'myControl',
      render() {
        this.domContainer.innerHTML =`<div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label for="controlValue">Link ID</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="controlValue">
          </div>
        </div>`;
        const inputField = document.getElementById('controlValue');

        inputField.value = this.domElement.querySelector('a[link-id]').getAttribute('link-id');
        inputField.onkeyup = (e) => {
          this.domElement.querySelector('a').setAttribute('link-id', e.target.value);
          this.applyChanges();
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

This is a pure JS equivalent